# Which t-test it the right one for my data?

Tags: r, t-test

I have the data set below.  Two Groups which were tested at 3 different timing. Between the tests, there were 5 weeks of training.  I think, I should do the t-test for dependent variable.  (I need this for my master thesis in physical education, so I don't need anything fancy.)

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(group = c("Experimentalgruppe", "Kontrollgruppe", 
"Experimentalgruppe", "Kontrollgruppe", "Kontrollgruppe", "Experimentalgruppe", 
"Kontrollgruppe", "Experimentalgruppe", "Experimentalgruppe", 
"Kontrollgruppe", "Experimentalgruppe", "Kontrollgruppe", "Kontrollgruppe", 
"Kontrollgruppe", "Kontrollgruppe", "Experimentalgruppe", "Experimentalgruppe", 
"Kontrollgruppe"), `t0 VO2 max` = c(47.6, 47.6, 47.6, 46.7818181818182, 
44.6, 41.3, 38, 43.5090909090909, 41.8727272727273, 45.1454545454545, 
44.0545454545455, 28.475, 38.6, 44.6, 40.4, 32.6, 40.4, 44.3272727272727
), `t1 VO2 max` = c(47.8727272727273, 46.5090909090909, 48.6909090909091, 
47.6, 46.2363636363636, 42.1454545454545, 40.7, 44.6, 43.2363636363636, 
47.8727272727273, 44.3272727272727, 30.9333333333333, 41.6, 45.4181818181818, 
42.9636363636364, 33.2666666666667, 38.6, 40.1), `t2 VO2 max` = c(48.6909090909091, 
42.9636363636364, 48.6909090909091, 46.2363636363636, 47.8727272727273, 
42.4181818181818, 38.6, 42.6909090909091, 43.7818181818182, 49.2363636363636, 
44.8727272727273, 30.2666666666667, 42.1454545454545, 47.6, 42.4181818181818, 
33.2666666666667, 42.9636363636364, 42.6909090909091)), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

---

I think this one is better to use

```
# A tibble: 18 x 4
group              `t0 VO2 max` `t1 VO2 max` `t2 VO2 max`
<chr>                     <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1 Experimentalgruppe         47.6         47.9         48.7
2 Kontrollgruppe             47.6         46.5         43.0
3 Experimentalgruppe         47.6         48.7         48.7
4 Kontrollgruppe             46.8         47.6         46.2
5 Kontrollgruppe             44.6         46.2         47.9
6 Experimentalgruppe         41.3         42.1         42.4
7 Kontrollgruppe             38           40.7         38.6
8 Experimentalgruppe         43.5         44.6         42.7
9 Experimentalgruppe         41.9         43.2         43.8
10 Kontrollgruppe             45.1         47.9         49.2
11 Experimentalgruppe         44.1         44.3         44.9
12 Kontrollgruppe             28.5         30.9         30.3
13 Kontrollgruppe             38.6         41.6         42.1
14 Kontrollgruppe             44.6         45.4         47.6
15 Kontrollgruppe             40.4         43.0         42.4
16 Experimentalgruppe         32.6         33.3         33.3
17 Experimentalgruppe         40.4         38.6         43.0
18 Kontrollgruppe             44.3         40.1         42.7
```

Comment: What hypothesis do you want to test? You must know that before you can test a hypothesis.

Comment: The question is, is there a significant change in VO2max between these two groups. The Experimentalgruppe has trained the secound 5 weeks with a mask

Comment: Between the first time and the final time? What about the middle time? (You’re allowed not to care about the middle time, but that’s a decision for you to make.)

Comment: no, between the first time and the second one (t0 and t1) and between the second and the third one (t1 and t2)

Comment: the test between the first and the second time (t0 and t1 ) is not realy nessesary for my master thesis. I manipulated the Experintalgroup after the second test (t1) and whant to know if there is a sicnificant difference between both groups after the third test (t2)

Comment: @Jugglerz: Because I can't comment (less than 50 reputation) I have to ask: Is the shape of your data correct. You have 10 subjects in your Kontrollgruppe and 8 in your Experimentalgruppe.

Comment: yes, it ist correct. I had to remove 2 subjects from Experimentalgruppe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would go about testing this.

In summary, it does not appear (from what I gather) that your treatment groups differ significantly from your control groups.

let's load your data, I call it "df_test"

```
df_test <- structure(list(group = c("Experimentalgruppe", "Kontrollgruppe", 
                         "Experimentalgruppe", "Kontrollgruppe", "Kontrollgruppe", "Experimentalgruppe", 
                         "Kontrollgruppe", "Experimentalgruppe", "Experimentalgruppe", 
                         "Kontrollgruppe", "Experimentalgruppe", "Kontrollgruppe", "Kontrollgruppe", 
                         "Kontrollgruppe", "Kontrollgruppe", "Experimentalgruppe", "Experimentalgruppe", 
                         "Kontrollgruppe"), `t0 VO2 max` = c(47.6, 47.6, 47.6, 46.7818181818182, 
                                                             44.6, 41.3, 38, 43.5090909090909, 41.8727272727273, 45.1454545454545, 
                                                             44.0545454545455, 28.475, 38.6, 44.6, 40.4, 32.6, 40.4, 44.3272727272727
                         ), `t1 VO2 max` = c(47.8727272727273, 46.5090909090909, 48.6909090909091, 
                                             47.6, 46.2363636363636, 42.1454545454545, 40.7, 44.6, 43.2363636363636, 
                                             47.8727272727273, 44.3272727272727, 30.9333333333333, 41.6, 45.4181818181818, 
                                             42.9636363636364, 33.2666666666667, 38.6, 40.1), `t2 VO2 max` = c(48.6909090909091, 
                                                                                                               42.9636363636364, 48.6909090909091, 46.2363636363636, 47.8727272727273, 
                                                                                                               42.4181818181818, 38.6, 42.6909090909091, 43.7818181818182, 49.2363636363636, 
                                                                                                               44.8727272727273, 30.2666666666667, 42.1454545454545, 47.6, 42.4181818181818, 
                                                                                                               33.2666666666667, 42.9636363636364, 42.6909090909091)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     -18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

First need to get your data in the proper format for analysis

```
library(dplyr)
df_ready <- tidyr::gather(df_test, Interval, VO, -(1), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Your test was done 3 times, I called this variable "interval", and I am just going to change the variable names to 1, 2, 3 for simplicity

```
df_ready$Interval <- as.factor(df_ready$Interval)
levels(df_ready$Interval)[levels(df_ready$Interval)=="t0 VO2 max"] <- "1"
levels(df_ready$Interval)[levels(df_ready$Interval)=="t1 VO2 max"] <- "2"
levels(df_ready$Interval)[levels(df_ready$Interval)=="t2 VO2 max"] <- "3"
```

lets set things up for a simple linear regression, but first get the data structured right

```
str(df_ready) # need to change "group" and "interval"
df_ready$group <- as.factor(df_ready$group)
df_ready$Interval <- as.factor(df_ready$Interval)
```

run model

```
model = lm(VO~group + Interval, data = df_ready)
summary(model) notice low t-values, most likely nothing is deviating significantly
anova(model) # anova is not-significant, suggesting, no further testing is required, But let's continue to see what happens

test <- aov(model)
TukeyHSD(test)
summary(test) # notice it's the same results as the other way of running an anova test
```

```
plot(VO~Interval,type ='n',xaxt = "n",data = df_ready, xlab="Time Interval", main= "VO Max Measurement Through Time")
points(df_ready$Interval[df_ready$group=='Kontrollgruppe'],df_ready$VO[df_ready$group=='Kontrollgruppe'],col='red',cex=2,pch=18)
points(df_ready$Interval[df_ready$group=='Experimentalgruppe'],df_ready$VO[df_ready$group=='Experimentalgruppe'],col='blue',cex=2,pch=7)
xtick<-seq(0, 3, by=1)
axis(1, at=xtick, labels = F)
df_ready$Interval <- as.factor(df_ready$Interval) # need to switch back temporarily to as.factor to create your x-axis labels
labels<- levels(df_ready$Interval)
text(x =  seq_along(labels), y = par("usr")[3] - (par("usr")[4] - par("usr")[3])/40, srt = 360, adj = 0.5,
     labels = labels, xpd = TRUE,cex = 1.5,font = 2)
df_ready$Interval <- as.numeric(df_ready$Interval) # flip back to as.numeric for adding the regression lines
abline(lm(df_ready$VO[df_ready$group=='Kontrollgruppe']~df_ready$Interval[df_ready$group=='Kontrollgruppe']),lwd=1,lty=1,col="red")
abline(lm(df_ready$VO[df_ready$group=='Experimentalgruppe']~df_ready$Interval[df_ready$group=='Experimentalgruppe']),lwd=1,lty=1,col="blue")
legend(2.5,48,cex=1.5,c('Kontrollgruppe','Experimentalgruppe'),fill=c('red','blue'), horiz=F)
```

Notice how regression lines are very close to eachother: Not surprising, given the results we got from the linear model.

Lets plot the predicted values from the model, R calls these "fitted" models

```
df_ready$fit <- predict(model)   #Add model fits to dataframe
```

box plot them

```
boxplot (df_ready$fit~df_ready$group, xlab = "Experimental Groups")
t.test(df_ready$fit~df_ready$group) # not significant
```

We can see box plots are very similar, and t'test is not significant, meaning your treatment did not increase or decrease the VO max of your subjects

Comment: Now i see, that there is no significant difference between Experimentalgruppe and Kontrollgruppe.
If i want to check the significance only on test time 2 and 3 (in my data, t1 and t2), where i have to change the code? The intervention startet after t1 (so maybe my mistake in describing the question)

so i think i have to compare t0/t1 and t1/t2

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please consider using base R, & commenting it extensively, when illustrating answers here w/ R code. Not everyone who will come to this page will be familiar w/ R, & not all of those will be able to read tidy-code. This is a Q&A site for *statistics*, not R.

Comment: Thank you for your infirmation.
I was migrated from the other forum to this one here. :-)

Comment: if my comment responds properly to your question, please up vote it. :)

Comment: @Jugglerz I have updated my code to do a test between all possible combinations, I did what's called a TukeyHSD test, and added it to the code underneath the linear model

But to be fair, it's not necessary here because the anova itself is not significant, and therefore looking at individual groups as you wish to is not necessary, I did it here anyways and, no surprise, nothing is significant.